# Return a fake year between a range using Faker?

Tags: python, date, random, range, faker

I am trying to create some fake years (just years not dates) in a range from 1800 to 1900 using Faker.

I have read [the docs](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.date_time.html) regarding fake dates and years and it seems like Faker.year() is the way forward. However there is no documentation regarding adding a range to .year(). Currently, it just outputs years post 1970.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need anything more than `import random ;  random.randint(1800, 1900)`

Comment: Why don't you just use `random.randint(1800,1900)`. Or if the format needs to be a datetime: `datetime.datetime(random.randint(1800,1900),1,1)` ?

Comment: Thank you DeepSpace, the simplest answer never came to me! If you provide your answer below I'll mark as complete

Comment: Thats very true Florian, yours and DeepSpace is the best approach, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

faker might be great for other, more complex things, but in this case `random.randint` is sufficient

```
from random import randint

randint(1800, 1900)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use date_between_dates for this. The below example gives a year between 2015 and 2019.

```
from faker import Faker

from datetime import datetime

f = Faker()

print(f.date_between_dates(date_start=datetime(2015,1,1), date_end=datetime(2019,12,31)).year)
```